# Autoresizing UINavigationBar in AnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

In my app I have a TabbarController. One of the tabs opens a View which starts the iPhone camera. This CameraView is part of a SDK which is developed by another company. So I can't modify the class of this CameraView.
My problem is that I have to implement a UINavigationBar in this CameraView. I've solved this through a annotationView (this navigationbar is not handled by a navigationcontroller):

```
[self.annotationView addSubview:navbar];
```

All works well except the autoresizing matter. If I turn the phone to landscape mode the navigationbar is too short. 
I have already tried to set Autoresizingmask but that doesn't help.
Do you have any ideas how I can force the navigationbar to autoresize?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adjust the frame of the navigationbar manually, instead of using autorotation.

```
-willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fio toInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)tio
{
    if(tio == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape)
        //set navbar frame 
    else
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the right way! But I used '(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation'

Comment: shouldAutorotate.. is used to specify which orientation are allowed. You should use willAutorotate.. To change the frame. Please accept answer if correct, thx. :)